# Wallet not updating with received bitcoin

Tags: transactions, wallet

I should have received an amount of bitcoins but my wallet balance in the client is still showing $0. The transfer occurred yesterday, while the client was not running. I confirmed the whole blockchain is updated and that the transaction appears at blockchain.info, yet the wallet still shows $0. What could cause this?

Comment: Does your wallet address at http://blockchain.info/address/<WALLETADDRESS> show the coins?

Comment: Yes it does: [link](http://blockchain.info/fb/1aqtfg)

Comment: If the address is really in your wallet, that is weird.

Comment: Are you sure that the number of blocks in your client is the same as the number on blockexplorer?: http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount

Comment: Yep, I just double checked and they match.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular that question is tagged bitcoin-qt, if this is closed as a duplicate should that other question be made more general and re-tagged?